# Parse data from webpage using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone please help me parse particular data from a web page? Here is the content on the webpage.

`{"sites":[{"id":"XX","name":"YY","url":"ZZ","username":"AA","password":"BB","siteId":"0"},{"id":"XX","name":"YY","url":"ZZ","username":"AA","password":"BB","siteId":"0"}]}`

I need just the id from the entire content. Please note we have id two times here in the content of webpage, so I need all id from the webpage.  Here is the code I have written to dump the web content, but unable to parse the data I need. Please help me.

```
def test(ip):
    url = 'http://%s/' % ip
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    webContent = response.read()
    print webContent
```

Answer (score 0):

your content is a json document, you can parse it with the [json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and use it as a python object:

```
import json

def test(ip):
    url = 'http://%s/' % ip
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    webContent = response.read()
    content = json.loads(webContent)
    print([site['id'] for site in content['sites']])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. IDs are printed something like this [u'1', u'2'] with 'u' infront of the IDs. Is there a way to get rid of those u's?

Comment: it's because those are unicode string in python2. If you don't care about that you can use str to change them to string:

    print([str(site['id']) for site in content['sites']])